# Corda docs have wrong instructions for installing JDK

Tags: corda

I'm posting this as a possible bug report because [this page](https://docs.corda.net/troubleshooting.html) says,

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> Please report any issues on our StackOverflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corda

---

Maybe these instructions for installing Java on Ubuntu are wrong (obsolete):

> https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html#id4
>
> **Java**
>
> 1. Open a new terminal and add the Oracle PPA to your repositories by typing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`. Press ENTER when prompted.
> 2. Update your packages list with the command `sudo apt update`
> 3. Install the Oracle JDK 8 by typing `sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer`.
> 4. Press Y when prompted and agree to the licence terms.

Because what I see when I do that is as follows:

```
cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
[sudo] password for cwellsx: 
 The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019.

The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html

Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle).

For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation).

Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.10, 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.

More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

For Oracle Java 11, see a different PPA -> https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15,4 kB]
Get:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                         
Get:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]                                    
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]          
Get:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [713 kB]            
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [22,6 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10,4 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [31,7 kB]
Get:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [574 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,1 kB]
Get:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [285 kB]
Get:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [70,9 kB]                
Get:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]                   
Get:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [978 kB]                         
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16,4 kB]                 
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [116 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]    
Get:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1 000 kB]
Get:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [253 kB]
Get:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [193 kB]
Get:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [453 kB]
Get:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 468 B]
Get:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7 920 B]
Fetched 5 179 kB in 6s (924 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                             
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$
```

Maybe (correct me if I'm wrong) the way to do that now is:

1. Download the `*.tar.gz` from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Unzip:

   ```
   cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo mkdir /opt/java
   cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo tar -zxf Downloads/jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/java
   ```
3. Add the following to `/etc/profile`

   ```
   # after `sudo tar -zxf Downloads/jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/java`
   export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_221
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```
4. Restart Ubuntu
5. Verify

   ```
   cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ echo $PATH
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin
   cwellsx@cwellsx-VirtualBox:~$ java -version
   java version "1.8.0_221"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
   ```

... which is like the installation instructions for Windows.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely obosolete, see the PPA page:
https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your notes and contribution!

I will pass the notes to the docs team and make changes accordingly.

Comment: Is this (i.e. Stack Overflow) the right place to be reporting any problems with that Corda documentation? I think I found another problem -- i.e. on https://docs.corda.net/building-a-cordapp-samples.html the three named samples don't exist -- there are many other samples at https://github.com/corda/samples but not apparently "trader-demo", "attachment-demo", and "bank-of-corda-demo".